# WSS 3.0 & VMWare

Tags: wss-3.0

I planning to shift my WSS 3.0 environment to VMWare.
I want to know what are the minimum hardware requirements?
especially Processor Speed & RAM.

Any whitepaper on the same would also be of great help!

Thanks for any help!

-saumil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TechNet - Determine hardware and software requirements (Windows SharePoint Services)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/bb684454.aspx)

> This article describes the hardware
>   and software requirements for
>   installing Windows SharePoint Services
>   3.0.

And to get deep into the specifics

[TechNet - Plan for performance and capacity (Windows SharePoint Services)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc288124%28office.12%29.aspx)

> guidance about choosing a farm
>   topology or hardware based on
>   availability requirements or
>   performance and capacity requirements.

Comment: Ok, I want to know what config is required for WSS 3.0 on VMWare. I think what you have provided is for general installation.

Comment: These guidelines map well to VMWare Virtual Machines in terms of memory requirements. You must ensure your hardware supports virtualisation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you shifting multiple Web Front Ends into a virtualized environment, or are you doing a small-scale "Basic" install with everything in one VM (not really recommended outside development environments)

These kinds of requests require some level of detail in order to be able to safely estimate any capacity planning requirements.

Comment: Here are the details -- I have three web front ends (Sharepoint WSS, Jhoomla based website (also .net based) and other professionally developed websites - and I have two web-servers called Cartika and Liquid Web. VMware can't be installed on Cartika because we are already on a VPS. Thx for help!

Comment: Forgot to add...I want to install VMware on Liquid web-server

Comment: So you're installing VMWare to host a SharePoint environment in a hosted dedicated server, correct?

The system requirements still match that of Microsoft-published documents in terms of RAM and CPU capability, but on top of that you have to ensure that the hardware on which you're running VMWare supports virtualisation to be able to get satisfactory performance.

You must also take into account the database capacities you will need, however it isn't considered best practice to virtualize the database server as this will result in very poor performance in SharePoint.